# React Router V6 how to stay on route after refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, shopify-app, ngrok

I am currently using the React (Vite)/Node.js template for Shopify, hosted on a Ngrok address.

Whenever I navigate to any page and refresh, the Ngrok hosted app puts me back at '/'.

How do I stay on the same page after a refresh? I've tried using local storage with useLocation() and useNavigate() but then I can't navigate back to previous pages.

I know this is a very simple fix but I've looked everywhere and can't figure it out.

```js
 return (
    <AppBridgeProvider
      config={{
        apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
        host: new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("host"),
        forceRedirect: true,
      }}
    >
      {/*// @ts-ignore */}
      <PolarisProvider i18n={translations}>
        <MyProvider>
              <Frame>
                <Page fullWidth>
                  <Layout>
                    <Routes>
                      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />      
                      <Route path="/campaigns" element={<CampaignDashboard />} />
                      <Route
                        path="/campaigns/create-campaign"
                        element={<CreateCampaignContainer />}
                      />

                      {/*TODO: 404 page for path='*' */}
                    </Routes>
                  </Layout>
                </Page>
              </Frame>
        </MyProvider>
      </PolarisProvider>
    </AppBridgeProvider>
  );
```

Comment: Are you using BrowserRouter or HashRouter?

Comment: What exactly is redirecting you to `"/"` upon navigation/page requests? We will likely need a more complete and comprehensive [mcve].

Comment: I am using BrowserRouter with default settings.
When I refresh the page, the entire application is reset and the pathname is just '/'. I should've used better wording, it's not a redirect, the app is being reset on refresh - is this an ngrok issue?